# Jenkins how to rename war file

Tags: jenkins, war, scp, mv

I have deployed a war file in a remote machine using Jenkins. Now I want to rename the war file through jenkins before it extracts the work folder? How can this be done? I tried post deployment action -> execute shell and mv file.war to new-file.war but it returns an error saying  : mv: cannot stat `file.war': No such file or directory.

Suppose there was something wrong with my path it would not even have gone to remote location. but for me, after scp' ing it to remote location thru jenkins, and when i try to do a mv, it fails.. What could the reason be??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to rename your local copy of the file after scp-ing it somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

Adding additional Step of `Execute shell` during `Add build Step` or `Add post-build action` stage, normal renaming shell command `mv` can be used to rename artifacts.

**Note: Make sure use the correct path(Relative to project/workspace root)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your mv command is probably executed in another directory than the one you are expecting.

To know the directory your script is running in without reading the jenkins / plugin documentation add

> echo "pwd of script is: " `pwd`

to your shell script and inspect the output of the jenkins build - that way you can be sure about the directory the script is run in.